# How to auto update fields in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have around 20 fields in my template and depending on an event on the page (the user click on a button which do some verifications on the server who return updated values for these fields), I want to auto update these fields who all belong to the object **user**. **I don't want to user jQuery** to update individually each of these fields. **Is there a way in meteor to AutoUpdate all the fields linked to an object in Meteor?**

Example of my template:

```
<template name="userForm">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Your name" value="{{user.first_name}}">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name" value="{{user.last_name}}">
</template>
```

The fields are well initialized on the page load, using the helpers:

```
Template.userForm.helpers({
    user: function(){
        return { first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe" };
    }
})
```

I want to update these fields in my template when in my code the object user is modified, such has:

```
user.first_name="Mark".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, that's exactly what meteor's liveHTML is for.

```
Session.setDefault('user', { first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe" });
Template.userForm.helpers({
    user: function() {
        return Session.get('user');
    }
})
```

and to set:

```
Session.set('user', OBJECT_FROM_SERVER);
```

But if you are interacting with the server, then why not just use a collection?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. So I understand that for the helpers values (first_name and last_name) to be dynamically updated, we have to store the user object and update it in the variable session.